# Select one row per group without specifying order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking-functions

Suppose I have this data:

```
create table People (ID int identity, Name nvarchar(50), Age int);   
insert into People values 
  ('Bill Jones', 50),
  ('Bill Jones', 12),
  ('Sam Smith', 23),
  ('Jill Brown', 44),
  ('Jill Brown', 67),
  ('Jill Brown', 3)
```

And this query:

```
select * from (
   select 
       ID, Name, Age, 
       row_number() over (partition by Name order by ID) [rownum]
   from People
) a where [rownum] = 1
```

It successfully returns me one person per unique name.

```
ID  NAME        AGE ROWNUM
1   Bill Jones  50  1
4   Jill Brown  44  1
3   Sam Smith   23  1
```

However, in order to use `row_number()`, I must specify an `order by`, causing the query plan to include an expensive sort operation.

[image: query plan]

I don't care about *which* person is returned; I just need one person per name.

Is there a way to do this without the sorting?

You can see my query and execution plan here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ee32/1/0

Comment: Try using `order by 1/0`, a fake sort. It might game the QO enough to drop the Sort.

Comment: Sorts aren't always expensive and don't trust the %s in the query plans. You can also try the variation `select Id, Name, Age from People where ID in (select min(ID) from people group by Name)`

Comment: I think I'm an idiot actually.. it has to sort by Name anyway in order to partition. Changing to `order by 1/0` does stop it ordering by ID *as well as* Name though.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know it optmised one or not but it shows record as you want...without order by clause/.....

```
Select * from People a where id in (Select Top(1) id from people b where name in
                                  (Select name from people group by name) and a.name=b.name)
```

[Sql Fidddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f158f/1)

Answer (score 1):

How about the query:

```
select 
    distinct Name, 
    (Select top 1 Age from People b where b.Name=a.Name) Age 
from People a
```

OR

```
select b.* From(
    select min(ID) ID from people group by Name
    ) a inner join People b on a.ID=b.ID
```

with all columns.
**FACT: None of these queries beat the query with ROW_NUMBER()!**

Comment: Interesting, but I actually have several columns other than Age, so I'd need a subquery for each.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider this query:

```
SELECT 
  a.* 
FROM 
  People a 
LEFT JOIN 
  People b 
ON
  (a.Name = b.Name AND a.id > b.id) 
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

When I run it in SQLFiddle, it seems to perform better:

Original query: `0.0146747`

Self join:      `0.0071784`

Comment: Where do you see those numbers? I can only see "1ms" for both. Anyway, I translated it to my real table, and it seems to be slower - two table scans instead of one scan and a sort. Interesting technique though!

Answer (score 1):

I actually see different ways to write the original query. You can also consider using `Common Table Expression`. Though i believe the optimization level will be almost the same. i did prefer `CTE` though.

```
with cte
as
(
    select ID, Name, Age, 
           row_number() over (partition by Name order by ID) [rownum]
    from People
)

select * 
from cte 
where [rownum] = 1
```